# Why are these two jQuery functions both not firing on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Okay, I have two jQuery functions.  One of them is a simple explode effect on a div.  The other function enhances the explode effect by sending particles in a circle around the div. When I click on the div with both functions set, it will only fire the explode effect and not the function with the debris on my site.

**Something Strange**

In jsfiddle the debris is working and not the explode, but on my site the explode effect is working but not the debris.

Here is the jsfiddle example: [jsfiddle.net/FYB98/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/FYB98/3/)

**Note**:  I'm using the same jQuery version for both my site and the jsfiddle example,  that's jquery-1.9.1.

This is my code

```
<style>
.debris {
 display: none;   
 position: absolute;
 width: 28px;
 height: 28px;
 background-color: #ff00ff;
 opacity: 1.0;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-radius: 8px;
}

#bubble {
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  left:150px;
  top:150px;
  width:32px;
  height:32px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  z-index: 9;
}
</style>
<div id="content">
    <div id="bubble"></div>
    <div id="dummy_debris" class="debris" />
</div>
<script>
// jQuery bubble pop animation
// Ben Ridout (c) 2013 - http://BenRidout.com/?q=bubblepop
// You're free to use this code with above attribution (in source is fine).

$(function(){
  // Document is ready
  $("#bubble").on("click", function(e) {
    pop(e.pageX, e.pageY, 13);
  });
});
 $( "#bubble" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggle( "explode", {pieces: 50 }, 2000);

});
function r2d(x) {
    return x / (Math.PI / 180);
  }

  function d2r(x) {
    return x * (Math.PI / 180);
  }

  function pop(start_x, start_y, particle_count) {
    arr = [];
    angle = 0;
    particles = [];
    offset_x = $("#dummy_debris").width() / 2;
    offset_y = $("#dummy_debris").height() / 2;

    for (i = 0; i < particle_count; i++) {
      rad = d2r(angle);
      x = Math.cos(rad)*(80+Math.random()*20);
      y = Math.sin(rad)*(80+Math.random()*20);
      arr.push([start_x + x, start_y + y]);
      z = $('<div class="debris" />');
      z.css({
          "left": start_x - offset_x,
          "top": start_y - offset_x
      }).appendTo($("#content"));
      particles.push(z);
      angle += 360/particle_count;
    }

    $.each(particles, function(i, v){
      $(v).show();
      $(v).animate(
        {
          top: arr[i][1], 
          left: arr[i][0],
          width: 4, 
          height: 4, 
          opacity: 0
        }, 600, function(){$(v).remove()
      });
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: both click handlers should be inside `$(function(){})`

Comment: You need to include `jQuery Ui` for this to work. As it is using easing.. Check this fiddle with jQueryUi enabled .. http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/FYB98/5/

Comment: Glad to have helped :) .. Checking the dev tools always helps if something stops working ..

Comment: @Sushanth-- I missed to see/load the comments.

Comment: @user1671639.. Not a problem ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your fiddle, it seems you missed to include [`jQuery UI`](http://jqueryui.com/).

Check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FYB98/8/)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't put second click event in `$(function)` handler. Put both events in `$(function)` handler

```
$(function(){
  // Document is ready
  $("#bubble").on("click", function(e) {
    pop(e.pageX, e.pageY, 13);
  });

$( "#bubble" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggle( "explode", {pieces: 50 }, 2000);

});
});
```

working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/FYB98/9/